# Import Json file to mongodb with join

Tags: json, mongodb

I have two Json files. I need to merge them in mongodb.

```
   {"indicate_public": "public",
   "indicate_compulsory": "man",
   "profile_photo": "Foto"}
```

and this is my second file:

```
  {"indicate_public": "public",
  "indicate_compulsory": "verplicht",
  "test_tooltip": "tooltip"}
```

each row should inserted seprate row in a new collection named :languages

Comment: Am I right that you want to merge the records from to separate files into a one mongo document? First, how do you want to match the records? Second, please give an example of how should the resulting document look.

Comment: Not one document. the result must be like this : `{
    "_id" : "Epp8iFpxhP7jaMTkg",
    "key" : "indicate_compulsory",
    "frVal" : "man",
    "nlVal" : "verplicht"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is not a tools in robomongo or Mongochef for importing this kind of data. So I write this codes in a js file in server/methods/publicationMethods.js

```
  readLanguageFile() {

  var fs = require('fs');
  var frfileName = process.env.PWD +'/both/I18N/fr/fr.i18n.json';
  var nlfileName = process.env.PWD +'/both/I18N/nl/nl.i18n.json';
  var frcontent = fs.readFileSync(frfileName, 'utf8')
  var nlcontent = fs.readFileSync(nlfileName, 'utf8')
  var frresult = JSON.parse(frcontent);
  var nlresult = JSON.parse(nlcontent);


    for (var key in frresult) {
             var param = key
             var frVal = frresult[key];
             var nlVal = nlresult[key];
              console.log('herein read json');
              if (frVal ==null)
              {
                frVal==""
              }
              if (nlVal ==null)
              {
                nlVal==""
              }
             var object = {}
             object.key=param
             object.frVal =frVal
             object.nlVal=nlVal
              //console.log('object',object);
             Languages.insert(object)

    }

},
```